# Stored procedure execution is too slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure which refer multiple tables (four to be specific i.e `RefurbRef`, `ActivationDetailRefurb`, `ActivationDetailReplaced`, `ReplacedData`) with of approx 1 lac of data on each table.

I need to bind the data from the stored procedure to UI on front end. When I tried executing the stored procedure on my SQL Server 2008 it took almost 20 minutes to execute and fetch the result. There's no way user's going to wait for that long gazing at the "please wait loading" user interface.

This is the procedure:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[uspLotFailureDetail]
     @fromDate varchar(50),
     @toDate varchar(50),
     @vendorName varchar(50),
     @modelName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    select 
        d.LOTQty, 
        ApprovedQty = count(distinct d.SerialNUMBER),
        d.DispatchDate,
        Installed = count(a.SerialNumber) + count(r.SerialNumber),
        DOA = sum(case when datediff(day, coalesce(a.ActivationDate,r.ActivationDate), f.RecordDate) between 0 and 10 then 1 else 0 end),
        Bounce = sum(case when datediff(day, coalesce(a.ActivationDate,r.ActivationDate), f.RecordDate) between 11 and 180 then 1 else 0 end)
    from 
        RefurbRef d 
    left join 
        ActivationDetailRefurb a on d.SerialNUMBER= a.SerialNumber
                                 and d.DispatchDate <= a.ActivationDate 
                                 and d.LOTQty = a.LOTQty
    left join 
        ActivationDetailReplaced r on d.SerialNUMBER= r.SerialNumber
                                   and d.DispatchDate <= r.ActivationDate
                                   and d.LOTQty = r.LotQty
                                   and (a.ActivationDate is null or a.ActivationDate <= d.DispatchDate)
    left join 
        ReplacedData f on f.OldSerialNumber = (coalesce (a.SerialNumber, r.SerialNumber))
                       and f.RecordDate >= (coalesce (a.ActivationDate, r.ActivationDate))
    where 
        d.DispatchDate between @fromDate and @toDate  
        and d.VendorName = @vendorName 
        and d.Model = @modelName
    group by 
        d.LOTQty, d.DispatchDate
END
```

There are two types of results the procedure extracts, Results based on Vendor and on Model. However if result is extracted based on Vendor i.e by using only `@fromDate`, `@toDate` and `@Vendor`, procedure takes less than 2 minutes to execute and get the result. But when all the four variables are used like in the procedure above it takes not less than 20 minutes to execute.

Is there any way I could optimize the query to increase the performance of the procedure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you may enhance performance by using indexes, you could also check the execution plan to see what part of the query takes long time

Comment: 20 minutes is very long... But without any details concerning table structure, indexes, row counts it is impossible to answer. Btw: You should not use a stored procedure only to  read data... In this case a VIEW or a single-statement UDF is better...

Comment: Please share the execution plan.

Comment: @Shnugo my tables are **RefurbRef** - 32 columns, 279216 rows: **ActivationDetailRefurb** - 8 columns, 96911 rows : **ActivationDetailReplaced** - 8 columns, 114693 rows : **ReplacedData** - 8 columns, 227808 rows. But I use only 4 columns  from each of the table Serial Number, Vendor, Model and Date's

Comment: " BY using only fromDate, toDate and Vendor, procedure takes less than 2 minutes to execute and get the result. But when all the four variables are used like in the procedure above it takes not less than 20 minutes to execute"



 For me it seems like its a Problems of Multiple Predicates which are narrowing down the estimation you could use 

 multi column statistics to avoid it just give it a try





Create index IX_RefurbRef_DispatchDate_VendorName_VendorName on  RefurbRef (dDispatchDate  ,VendorName  ,VendorName)
Include 
(LOTQty, SerialNUMBER ,DispatchDate)

Comment: @KC, Your tables aren't even large... Please provide more details (Table structure, indexes)

Answer (score 0):

Given the information provided I would look at the **RefurbRef.model** number to see if there is a covering index on this field. I would bet there is not based on it jumping to 20 minutes once you added this criteria.  Additionally, I would change your variables to dates from varchar.

```
@fromDate Date,   
@toDate Date,
```

Hope this helps,
Jason